# tvOS supports sqlite database?

Tags: swift, sqlite, tvos

Does tvOS supports SQLite database to store data, because I have a huge data to store in app. But I heard that tvOS doesn't support SQLite database. Can some one answer me on this doubt and if any link is also appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is your data? `tvOS` allows only 200MB of custom data per app, and this data must be purgable (like caches or something). And format doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the following [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH12-SW5) on the Apple Documentation. It states that:

"your app can only access 500 KB of persistent storage that is local to the device (using the NSUserDefaults class). Outside of this limited local storage, all other data must be purgeable by the operating system when space is low"

So, the short answer is that yes, tvOS supports SQLite databases, but the data you store is not going to be persistent if you store on device since the data *can be* purged.